How to Integrate ReactJs or NextJs Microfrontend components in non React App

Lets say if I create microfrontend components using React Vite
App by using plugin vite-module-federation...

Now consumption of these components is very easy if I consume it in
my Host Microfrontend App which also built with React Vite App
using vite-module-federation


Lets say if I create microfrontend components using NextJs by using plugin Next Module Federation...

Now consumption of these components is very easy if I consume it in
my Host Microfrontend App which also built with NextJs
using Next Module Federation




But my use-case is different I want to integrate those components in
non-react App e.g Vanilla JS Project, Yii Framework View, Laravel
Framework

Below is the config file of my React Vite App
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import federation from '@originjs/vite-plugin-federation';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    federation({
      name: 'todo-components',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './List': './src/components/List',
        './Input': './src/components/Input',
      },
      shared: ['react', 'react-dom'],
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    modulePreload: false,
    target: 'esnext',
    minify: false,
    cssCodeSplit: false,
  },
});


But I'm not able to extract components, from remoteEntry.js file, if I want to integrate components, lets say in VanillaJs project
I'm just pasting below Scripts tag, you can assume there is a Div container with id='react-root'
    <!-- React and ReactDOM CDN -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

    <!-- remoteEntry.js bundle downloading -->
    <script type="module" src="http://localhost:4173/assets/remoteEntry.js"></script>
    

    <!-- Got Below Snippet From ChatGPT -->
    <!-- Trying to Extract Component, But getting error on get -->
    <script>
         (async () => {
             const module = await window['todo-components'].get('./Input');
             const MyReactComponent = module.default;
             const rootElement = document.getElementById('react-root');
             ReactDOM.render(
             React.createElement(MyReactComponent, { prop: 'value' }), rootElement);
         })();
    </script>


